# Linear algebra, polynomials and vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

if $R_3[x]$ is all the poly. with a power less than 3 that all of its coefficients are from $\mathrm{R}$ (real)
is $4x^{-2}$  $\in$ to $R_3[x]$ ?
and all of the poly with negative powers, (because they are smaller than 3)

Comment: No, unless your textbook uses an unconventional definition of polynomials.

Comment: ok, thanks!!!! so just to be clear, $R_3[x]$ is all the poly. with coe from R and the power is from 0 to 3 ?

Comment: Yes, polynomials of order three means that the maximal exponent (which, for polynomials, is always a non-negative integer) is $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Degree of a Polynomial, unless otherwise stated starts from $0$. We generally don't consider negatives.

Comment: ok, thank you ! now I get it, from 0 to y (including y)
$R_y[x]$